# Node.js spawn arguments causing git update-index to fail

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, ecmascript-6, spawn

I have a simple function to run `git update-index`.

```
exports.gitUpdateIndex = (path, pattern) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const error = [];
    const opt = {
      cwd: path
    };
    const process = spawn("git", ["update-index", "--chmod=+x", pattern], opt);
    process.on("close", () => {
      if (error.length > 0) {
        reject(error);
      }
      resolve();
    });
    process.stderr.on("data", data => error.push(data.toString().trim()));
  });
};
```

And I am trying to call it like -

```
await gitUpdateIndex(dirPath, "./*.sh");
```

But this is throwing an error like -

```
[
  "Ignoring path *.sh\nfatal: git update-index: cannot chmod +x '*.sh'"
]
```

## EDIT:

Seems like passing the absolute path to the function fixes it instead of an unix glob pattern.

```
await gitUpdateIndex(dirPath, "C:\\test\\hello.sh");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define every argument as individual array element:

```
spawn("git", ['update-index', '--chmod=+x', pattern], opt)
```

You are currently doing the equivalent to

```
git 'update-index --chmod=+x ./*.sh'
```

(note the quotes)

Comment: I updated the answer based on your suggestion but now its throwing a different error.